# 'script/console test' with spork and rspec not loading the whole environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, irb, script-console, spork

I'm trying to load up console to interact with some of my rspec mocking helpers. I expected that running `script/console test` would load an env similar to when I run `spec`. However, this doesn't appear to be the case. It looks like `spec_helper` is never loaded. Or, if it is, it's not actually running through the logic because spork has polluted it a bit.

In short, is there a quick and easy way to get an interactive rspec party going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load rspec with the following once the console is loaded:

`require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/spec/spec_helper"`

Comment: require "#{Rails::root.to_s}/spec/spec_helper"

Comment: FYI this answer is substantially out of date (no criticism of answerers, just warning newcomers :-)

Answer (score 0):

`RAILS_ROOT` is long-since deprecated. You can now load rspec in the console thus:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/spec/spec_helper"
```